# Jquery on click is not getting updated value of textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Alright, so I am trying to get the value of a textarea dynamically added from jquery. But it always seems to get the default value of it.

Heres the code:

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.savechanges',function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var rowid = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var text = $(".textbox-" + rowid).val();
    var datum = $("#date").val();

    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url : 'php/savechanges.php',    //Here you will fetch records 
        data :  'rowid='+ rowid + "&date=" + datum + "&text=" + text,     //Pass $id
        success : function(data){
          alert('Dina ändringar har blivit sparade!');
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="text">Ändra din text för denna dag</label>
  <textarea class="form-control textbox-<?php echo $singleRow['id'];?>" name="textruta" id="text">.
    <?php echo $singleRow['textruta'];?>
  </textarea>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-success savechanges" data-dismiss="modal" data-id="<?php echo $singleRow['id'];?>">
  Spara ändringar
</button>
```

So the issue here is that the `$(".textbox-" + rowid).val()` always gets the value added by jQuery and not the updated version.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems to work fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/nv9pjuuL/

Comment: The thing is, the textarea is created in another file and put on the page with jquery in a bootstrap modal. And when I try to post the result on the main page, jquery can't seem to access the updated content in the textarea.

Comment: Also tried the same with the date input, but that doesn't get updated either when I change it.

Comment: Try using .html() or .text() to retrieve instead of .val()

Comment: Neither works sadly. :(

Comment: are u sure that `.textbox-"id"` is correct formatted after echoing?

Comment: Yes. Jquery always takes the default text. The echo from the database is always what jquery gets even if I write something in the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Im create file index.php on my server and create this code

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
 $singleRow['id'] = 1;
 $singleRow['textruta'] = "test";
?>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="text">Andra din text for denna dag</label>
  <textarea class="form-control textbox-<?php echo $singleRow['id'];?>" name="textruta" id="text"><?php echo $singleRow['textruta'];?></textarea>
</div>
<input type="text" id="date" value="05/04/2017"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-success savechanges" data-dismiss="modal" data-id="<?php echo $singleRow['id'];?>">
  Spara andringar
</button>
<script>

$(".savechanges").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var rowid = $(this).data('id');
    var text = $(".textbox-" + rowid).val();
    var datum = $("#date").val();
console.log("start");
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url : '/seo-service/ajax/savechanges.php',    //Here you will fetch records 
        data :  'rowid='+ rowid + "&date=" + datum + "&text=" + text,     //Pass $id
        success : function(data){
            console.log(data);
          alert('Dina andringar har blivit sparade!');
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

after this im create new file "savechanges.php"

```
    <?php

var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

everything okey. I hope this example help you

Comment: I think problem on url, maybe try /php/savechanges.php (slash before "php")

Comment: The problem is not on the recieving end. Its a problem on the sending end.

Comment: How? What's your plan?

Comment: http://need-survive.com/seo-service/ajax/ <- link on my example, look on console, im return all data from "savechanges.php"